# problem with template hook suggestion for user profile

Tags: views

I recently did install a Drupal theme and did take the default views for contents to view user profiles it works properly till you click on the link to the user profile the Ajax loads a blank page , but when I try the same view without the theme's view formatter it works properly tried adding hook suggestion for user profiles but nothing seems to work.

How do I solve that?

Here's the default code for hook suggestion

```
function other_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    $suggest = "page__node__{$vars['node']->type}";
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $suggest;
  }

  $status = drupal_get_http_header("status");  
  if($status == "404 Not Found") {      
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__404';
  }

  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' ){
    $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page--taxonomy--vocabulary--' . $term->vid;
  }
}
```